# Building wheel for essentia

Tags: python, audio-analysis

import essentia
I installed anaconda in my local machine. I need to use essentia for audio analysis and audio-based music information retrieval.

However, there is error when I do " pip install essentia "

"Building wheel for essentia (setup.py)...error"

Anyone has some idea how to fix it?

Thanks

https://pypi.org/project/essentia/
https://essentia.upf.edu/essentia_python_tutorial.html

Comment: what error?  what is your local machine running?  how on earth can anyone guess what the error message is?

Comment: @Angela welcome to StackOverflow. Read this, please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.